# How can I sort a list of cards with randomly generated numbers inside of them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, random-seed, card

I generate cards on a button press. These cards have a randomly generated number between 0 and 100. I am trying to setup a component or function that would allow me to sort all of these cards in numerical order ascending or descending, or both, when I click the sort button. I have tried the following code. Keep in mind, this is all contained within the same App component.

The random numbers are generated in the add card component.

I feel like I'm super close, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
  const sortTypes = {
    up: {
      class: "sort-up",
      fn: (a, b) => a.number - b.number,
    },

    down: {
      class: "sort-down",
      fn: (a, b) => b.number - a.number,
    },

    default: {
      class: "sort",
      fn: (a, b) => a,
    },
  };

  const sortAll = () => {
    state = {
      currentSort: 'default'
    };

    onSortChange = () => {
      const { currentSort } = this.state;
      let nextSort;

      if (currentSort === 'down') nextSort = 'up';
      else if (currentSort === 'up') nextSort = 'default';
      else if (currentSort === 'default') nextSort = 'down';

      this.setState({
        currentSort: nextSort
      });
    };

    };
  

  return (
    <body>
      <header>
        <div className="ui buttons">
          <button type="button" onClick={addCard} className="ui button mb-1 mt-1 mr-1"><i className="plus icon"></i>Add Card</button>
          <div className="or mb-1 mt-1"></div>
          <button type="button" onClick={sortAll} className="ui positive button mb-1 mt-1 mr-1"><i className="redo icon"></i>Sort All</button>
        </div>
      </header>
```

Comment: Would be awesome if you could Sandbox this.

Comment: `sortAll` sort of looks like a react component, it's not named like one but it has state... but you are attaching as a callback? Where is `onSortChange` called to "select" the sort function you want to use? Where do you apply any sort function?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-mirzakhani-nw5ow?file=/src/index.js

Comment: There's a link to the codesandbox. The onSortChange is on line 72. The sort function should be applied on line 94.

Comment: I feel like I started doing it correctly but I've never done anything like this in React so I wasn't exactly sure where everything needed to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. Functional components are "instanceless" so there is no defined `this` to reference.
2. `onSortChange` is the button `onClick` handler you want to use to update the current sort.

## Solution

1. Move the `currentSort` to component state in a `useState` hook.

   ```
   const [currentSort, setCurrentSort] = useState("default");
   ```
2. Fix the `onSortChange` handler to correctly update state.

   ```
   const onSortChange = () => {
     let nextSort;

     if (currentSort === "down") nextSort = "up";
     else if (currentSort === "up") nextSort = "default";
     else if (currentSort === "default") nextSort = "down";

     setCurrentSort(nextSort);
   };
   ```
3. Use an in-line "sort" in the render return. Remember that `array.prototype.sort` is an in-place sort, i.e. it mutates the array. To get around accidentally mutating state first copy the array.

   ```
   {cards
     .slice() // <-- copy
     .sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn) // <-- select sort function
     .map((cardNumber, index) => (
       <MainCard
         number={cardNumber.number}
         key={cardNumber.id}
         onRemove={() => removeCard(cardNumber.id)}
       />
     ))}
   ```
4. Attach correct handler to button

   ```
   <button
     type="button"
     onClick={onSortChange}
     className="ui positive button mb-1 mt-1 mr-1"
   >
     <i className="redo icon"></i>Sort All
   </button>
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-cards-with-randomly-generated-numbers-inside-of-them]

Full Code:

```
const generateId = (seed = 0) => () => seed++;

const getRandomNumber = function (min, max) {
  let getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
  return getRandom;
};

const sortTypes = {
  up: {
    class: "sort-up",
    fn: (a, b) => a.number - b.number
  },

  down: {
    class: "sort-down",
    fn: (a, b) => b.number - a.number
  },

  default: {
    class: "sort",
    fn: (a, b) => a
  }
};

const MainCard = ({ number, onRemove }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <button
        onClick={onRemove}
        className="ui mini red basic icon button"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "0",
          right: "0"
        }}
      >
        X
      </button>
      {number}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [currentSort, setCurrentSort] = useState("default");

  const addCard = () => {
    setCards((cards) => [
      ...cards,
      {
        id: generateId(),
        number: getRandomNumber(0, 101)
      }
    ]);
  };

  const removeCard = (id) => {
    setCards((cards) => cards.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
  };

  const onSortChange = () => {
    let nextSort;

    if (currentSort === "down") nextSort = "up";
    else if (currentSort === "up") nextSort = "default";
    else if (currentSort === "default") nextSort = "down";

    setCurrentSort(nextSort);
  };

  return (
    <body>
      <header>
        <div className="ui buttons">
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={addCard}
            className="ui button mb-1 mt-1 mr-1"
          >
            <i className="plus icon"></i>Add Card
          </button>
          <div className="or mb-1 mt-1"></div>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={onSortChange}
            className="ui positive button mb-1 mt-1 mr-1"
          >
            <i className="redo icon"></i>Sort All
          </button>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className="card-container">
        {cards
          .slice()
          .sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn)
          .map((cardNumber) => (
            <MainCard
              number={cardNumber.number}
              key={cardNumber.id}
              onRemove={() => removeCard(cardNumber.id)}
            />
          ))}
      </div>

      <aside className="showHide"></aside>

      <footer>
        <h3 className="text-center text-muted">Footer</h3>
      </footer>
    </body>
  );
}
```